# Why is YouTube making requests to ourdomain.example.com/error_204

Tags: javascript, wordpress, youtube, csrf

We have a WordPress blog running under via a reverse Proxy under `ourdomain.example.com/blog` which embeds YouTube videos.

Now we are seeing requests in the chrome network tab to

```text
POST https://ourdomain.example.com/error_204?a=logerror&t=jserror&type=SyntaxError&msg=Failed%20to%20execute%20%27postMessage%27%20on%20%27Window%27%3A%20Invalid%20target%20origin%20%27data%3A%27%20in%20a%20call%20to%20%27postMessage%27.&line=Not%20available&level=WARNING&client.name=1
```

This requests lead to problems in our main software (Magento, under '/', showing CSRF problems)

We could just block those requests in the server but we want to understand why they are made.

Did anybody see those requests before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was a wrong embed code of the YouTube video

```html
<iframe  width="600" height="560" &" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" allow="autoplay" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxx?
```

There was a wrong & sign, caused by some WordPress template builder

Answer (score 2):

The YouTube player is apparently attempting to send an internal error report to Google servers, via the endpoint `http://youtube.com/error_204`, `http://youtube-nocookie.com/error_204` or similar. For that purpose, it uses the relative URI `/error_204`; but for some reason, this relative URI is resolved relative to *your* domain name, not YouTube’s.

What you should do is ensure that the link to the YouTube video points to YouTube’s domain, not your own. I presume that this is a problem with the configuration of the reverse proxy, but I am unable to say much more without further detail.

Answer (score 1):

The error is originating from YouTube trying to access something on `data:` which isn't https, or potentially the video is not visible when loaded.
Just search for `data:` in your project, I don't know what you've got that would be using it.

The error message itself is fairly unhelpful.